# Need to find a count of unique items in one column based on a value in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to find the unique count of items in a column based on a criteria or condition in another column.

### Example

**UserID        Cred Type**

Ramesh        Desktop
Ramesh        Desktop
Ramesh        Mobile
Visu              Desktop
Amar             Mobile
Visu              Desktop
Ramesh        Desktop
Dinesh          SMS
Ramesh        SMS
Dinesh          Mobile
Ramesh        SMS
Visu              SMS

### Expected Result:

Count of unique users using Desktop: 2

Count of unique users using Mobile: 3

Count of unique users using SMS: 3

I do need a excel formula where I can provide inputs like "Desktop" or "Mobile" or "SMS" and get the corresponding count.

I do need a single formula to do this since the dataset that I am going to work has around 40-50K rows with 9-10 columns. Also I need to do this each week, so I want to eliminate the manual work as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Build a tabular pivot table over your data with only [Cred Type] and [UserID] as row labels, then do COUNTIF:

```
COUNTIF([col/range of Cred Type],[input cell])
```

over that table.  Be sure to set the pivot to "Repeat Item Labels", so that there are no blank spots.

Answer (score 0):

You want a formula, but a formula is not the best way to do this. This formula does it -

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B13=B2,IF(A2:A13<>"",MATCH(A2:A13,A2:A13,0))),ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2)+1),1))`

It's an array formula, so you must type it in and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shft</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> so it ends up with curly brackets `{ }` around it.

A better option would be to use a pivot table!